# Determine the minimum and maximum number of paths on a $2N\times 2N$ board

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

[image: Question]

Here a path refers to a series of connected segments.
I have tried out small cases and have conjectured that the minimum is $4N$ and the maximum is $2N^2+2N+1$.

Construction for minimum:

[image]

Construction for maximum:

[image]

However, I do not know how to prove that these are the minimum/maximum. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: @Qise the first path is the ">" at the left, the second path is the bigger ">" in the centre, the third is the one at the top right corner and the fourth is the one at the bottom right corner.

Comment: I think your minimum diagram has $4N-1$ paths, since the main diagonal is common on both sides. Also, I feel this could be treated as a graph theory problem. Though I wouldn't know how to go down that approach

Comment: Don't use images for text or mathematics. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired. Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).

Comment: Where did you encounter that problem statement?  You are required to credit the original source of all material originally written by others; see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minimum:
The $8N$ edges of the board give $8N$ path endpoints, so there are at least $4N$ paths. The first example has $4N$ paths, so that is indeed the minimum.

Maximum:
The total length of the paths is $2(2N)^2$ segments, since each square has two segments. To get the maximum number of paths out of these segments, the paths need to be as short as possible.
The end points at the edge of the board can have as their shortest paths four paths of length 1 at the corners of the board, but all the other edges will need paths of length at least two because they have to start and end in different squares. The shortest possible loop is of length 4, a small diamond square.
The best possible case is therefore when $8$ of the $8N$ end points are used up by paths of length 1, and the remaining $8N-8$ endpoints as paths of length 2. That would give $4+(4N-4)$ paths with a total length of $8N-4$. The remaining $8N^2-8N+4$ segments would at best form $2N^2-2N+1$ loops of length 4. Together that would give at most $4+(4N-4)+(2N^2-2N+1) = 2N^2+2N+1$ paths.
The second example shows that this is indeed possible.